# AudioSink unknown error

Tags: redhawksdr

I would like to build an FM/AM trasmitter/receiver to test my USRP on Redhawk and I downloaded audio-components from GitHub Axios-Engineering repository.
I tried to built these waveform in which I run:
-SigGen,DataConverter and AudioSink;
-AudioTestSource and AudioSink;
In both cases I got this error:
`ERROR:ApplicationFactory_impl - Failed to instantiate component: 'AudioTestSource' with component id: 'AudioTestSource_1:audioTesat_134_170515794_1 assigned to device: 'DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da'  in waveform 'audioTesat_134_170515794_1';'configure' failed with Unknown Exception error occurred near line:3275 in file:ApplicationFactory_impl.cpp;
TRACE:PropertySet_impl - Query all properties
TRACE:PropertySet_impl - Query returning 3 properties
WARN:ApplicationFactory_impl - CF::ExecutableDevice::terminate failed for DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da; CORBA::Exception name: InvalidProcess`

I worked on CentOS6.5, RedHawk 1.9 and I installed and included each libraries.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: this is the log
`DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:Issuing event for DCE:9da85ebc-6503-48e7-af36-b77c7ad0c2b4 ({'fivemin': 0.34999999999999998, 'fifteenmin': 0.28000000000000003, 'onemin': 0.23000000000000001} != {'fivemin': 0.35999999999999999, 'fifteenmin': 0.28000000000000003, 'onemin': 0.28999999999999998})
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:Issuing event for DCE:6565bffd-cb09-4927-9385-2ecac68035c7 (2966 != 2938)
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:Eventing for properties ['DCE:9da85ebc-6503-48e7-af36-b77c7ad0c2b4', 'DCE:6565bffd-cb09-4927-9385-2ecac68035c7']
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:sendPropertiesEvent ['DCE:9da85ebc-6503-48e7-af36-b77c7ad0c2b4', 'DCE:6565bffd-cb09-4927-9385-2ecac68035c7']
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:sendEvent CORBA.Any(CORBA.TypeCode("IDL:ExtendedEvent/PropertySetChangeEventType:1.0"), ossie.cf.ExtendedEvent.PropertySetChangeEventType(sourceId='DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da', sourceName='', properties=[ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='DCE:9da85ebc-6503-48e7-af36-b77c7ad0c2b4', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TypeCode("IDL:CF/Properties:1.0"), [ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='fivemin', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_double, 0.35999999999999999)), ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='fifteenmin', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_double, 0.28000000000000003)), ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='onemin', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_double, 0.28999999999999998))])), ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='DCE:6565bffd-cb09-4927-9385-2ecac68035c7', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_long, 2938))])) {}
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:load(/components/AudioTestSource/cpp/AudioTestSource, EXECUTABLE)
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:Creating dir components
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:Creating dir AudioTestSource
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:Creating dir cpp
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:File /components/AudioTestSource/cpp/AudioTestSource has reference count 0 and local file existence is False
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:Loading Tree /components/AudioTestSource/cpp/AudioTestSource components/AudioTestSource/cpp [CF.FileSystem.FileInformationType(name='AudioTestSource', kind=PLAIN, size=2378971L, fileProperties=[ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='CREATED_TIME', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_ulonglong, 1400751415L)), ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='MODIFIED_TIME', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_ulonglong, 1400751415L)), ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='LAST_ACCESS_TIME', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_ulonglong, 1400751415L)), ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='READ_ONLY', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_boolean, False)), ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='IOR_AVAILABLE', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TypeCode("IDL:omg.org/CORBA/StringSeq:1.0"), []))])]
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:Reading file AudioTestSource -> components/AudioTestSource/cpp/AudioTestSource
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:Copy file /components/AudioTestSource/cpp/AudioTestSource -> /var/redhawk/sdr/dev/.DevMgr_wifiunipi-154-219.unipi.it/GPP_wifiunipi-154-219_unipi_it/components/AudioTestSource/cpp/AudioTestSource
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:execute(/components/AudioTestSource/cpp/AudioTestSource, [ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='STACK_SIZE', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_ulong, 0L)), ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='PRIORITY', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_ulong, 0L))], [ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='NAMING_CONTEXT_IOR', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_string, 'IOR:010000002b00000049444c3a6f6d672e6f72672f436f734e616d696e672f4e616d696e67436f6e746578744578743a312e30000001000000000000007800000001010200100000003133312e3131342e3135342e31333400f90a00000e000000ff0086c67d5301001c7e0000000400000300000000000000080000000100000000545441010000001c00000001000000010001000100000001000105090101000100000009010100035454410800000086c67d5301001c7e')), ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='COMPONENT_IDENTIFIER', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_string, 'AudioTestSource_1:Audio_test_waveform_142_114653655_1')), ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='NAME_BINDING', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_string, 'AudioTestSource_1'))])
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:Running /var/redhawk/sdr/dev/.DevMgr_wifiunipi-154-219.unipi.it/GPP_wifiunipi-154-219_unipi_it/components/AudioTestSource/cpp/AudioTestSource /var/redhawk/sdr/dev/.DevMgr_wifiunipi-154-219.unipi.it/GPP_wifiunipi-154-219_unipi_it
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:Popen /var/redhawk/sdr/dev/.DevMgr_wifiunipi-154-219.unipi.it/GPP_wifiunipi-154-219_unipi_it/components/AudioTestSource/cpp/AudioTestSource ['/var/redhawk/sdr/dev/.DevMgr_wifiunipi-154-219.unipi.it/GPP_wifiunipi-154-219_unipi_it/components/AudioTestSource/cpp/AudioTestSource', 'NAMING_CONTEXT_IOR', 'IOR:010000002b00000049444c3a6f6d672e6f72672f436f734e616d696e672f4e616d696e67436f6e746578744578743a312e30000001000000000000007800000001010200100000003133312e3131342e3135342e31333400f90a00000e000000ff0086c67d5301001c7e0000000400000300000000000000080000000100000000545441010000001c00000001000000010001000100000001000105090101000100000009010100035454410800000086c67d5301001c7e', 'COMPONENT_IDENTIFIER', 'AudioTestSource_1:Audio_test_waveform_142_114653655_1', 'NAME_BINDING', 'AudioTestSource_1']
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:execute() --> 7456
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:APPLICATIONS {7456: <subprocess.Popen object at 0x1248250>}
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:load(/components/AudioSink/cpp/AudioSink, EXECUTABLE)
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:Creating dir components
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:Creating dir AudioSink
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:Creating dir cpp
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:File /components/AudioSink/cpp/AudioSink has reference count 0 and local file existence is False
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:Loading Tree /components/AudioSink/cpp/AudioSink components/AudioSink/cpp [CF.FileSystem.FileInformationType(name='AudioSink', kind=PLAIN, size=1854013L, fileProperties=[ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='CREATED_TIME', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_ulonglong, 1400751287L)), ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='MODIFIED_TIME', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_ulonglong, 1400751287L)), ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='LAST_ACCESS_TIME', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_ulonglong, 1400751287L)), ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='READ_ONLY', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_boolean, False)), ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='IOR_AVAILABLE', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TypeCode("IDL:omg.org/CORBA/StringSeq:1.0"), []))])]
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:Reading file AudioSink -> components/AudioSink/cpp/AudioSink
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:Copy file /components/AudioSink/cpp/AudioSink -> /var/redhawk/sdr/dev/.DevMgr_wifiunipi-154-219.unipi.it/GPP_wifiunipi-154-219_unipi_it/components/AudioSink/cpp/AudioSink
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:execute(/components/AudioSink/cpp/AudioSink, [ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='STACK_SIZE', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_ulong, 0L)), ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='PRIORITY', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_ulong, 0L))], [ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='NAMING_CONTEXT_IOR', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_string, 'IOR:010000002b00000049444c3a6f6d672e6f72672f436f734e616d696e672f4e616d696e67436f6e746578744578743a312e30000001000000000000007800000001010200100000003133312e3131342e3135342e31333400f90a00000e000000ff0086c67d5301001c7e0000000400000300000000000000080000000100000000545441010000001c00000001000000010001000100000001000105090101000100000009010100035454410800000086c67d5301001c7e')), ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='COMPONENT_IDENTIFIER', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_string, 'AudioSink_1:Audio_test_waveform_142_114653655_1')), ossie.cf.CF.DataType(id='NAME_BINDING', value=CORBA.Any(CORBA.TC_string, 'AudioSink_1'))])
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:Running /var/redhawk/sdr/dev/.DevMgr_wifiunipi-154-219.unipi.it/GPP_wifiunipi-154-219_unipi_it/components/AudioSink/cpp/AudioSink /var/redhawk/sdr/dev/.DevMgr_wifiunipi-154-219.unipi.it/GPP_wifiunipi-154-219_unipi_it
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:Popen /var/redhawk/sdr/dev/.DevMgr_wifiunipi-154-219.unipi.it/GPP_wifiunipi-154-219_unipi_it/components/AudioSink/cpp/AudioSink ['/var/redhawk/sdr/dev/.DevMgr_wifiunipi-154-219.unipi.it/GPP_wifiunipi-154-219_unipi_it/components/AudioSink/cpp/AudioSink', 'NAMING_CONTEXT_IOR', 'IOR:010000002b00000049444c3a6f6d672e6f72672f436f734e616d696e672f4e616d696e67436f6e746578744578743a312e30000001000000000000007800000001010200100000003133312e3131342e3135342e31333400f90a00000e000000ff0086c67d5301001c7e0000000400000300000000000000080000000100000000545441010000001c00000001000000010001000100000001000105090101000100000009010100035454410800000086c67d5301001c7e', 'COMPONENT_IDENTIFIER', 'AudioSink_1:Audio_test_waveform_142_114653655_1', 'NAME_BINDING', 'AudioSink_1']
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:execute() --> 7457
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:APPLICATIONS {7456: <subprocess.Popen object at 0x1248250>, 7457: <subprocess.Popen object at 0x1248210>}
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:terminate(7456)
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:{7456: <subprocess.Popen object at 0x1248250>, 7457: <subprocess.Popen object at 0x1248210>}
ERROR:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:Child process 7457 terminated with signal 11
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:unload(/components/AudioTestSource/cpp/AudioTestSource)
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:{}
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:terminate(7457)
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:{}
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:unload(/components/AudioSink/cpp/AudioSink)
DEBUG:DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da:{}`

This is the node LOG:
`INFO:DomainManager_impl - Installing application /waveforms/Audio_test_waveform/Audio_test_waveform.sad.xml
DEBUG:ComponentInfo - Loading component properties from /components/AudioTestSource/AudioTestSource.prf.xml
DEBUG:ComponentInfo - Parsing component properties
DEBUG:ComponentInfo - Loading component properties from /components/AudioSink/AudioSink.prf.xml
DEBUG:ComponentInfo - Parsing component properties
DEBUG:ApplicationFactory_impl - UsesDevice Impl Vec of length 0
DEBUG:ApplicationFactory_impl - Trying to find the device
DEBUG:ImplementationInfo - Attempting to match allocation properties
DEBUG:ImplementationInfo - Done matching allocation properties
DEBUG:ApplicationFactory_impl - Assigned component AudioTestSource_1 to DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da
DEBUG:ApplicationFactory_impl - **PASSED** COMP INST_ID:AudioTestSource_1 IMPL:cpp
DEBUG:ApplicationFactory_impl - UsesDevice Impl Vec of length 0
DEBUG:ApplicationFactory_impl - Trying to find the device
DEBUG:ImplementationInfo - Attempting to match allocation properties
DEBUG:ImplementationInfo - Done matching allocation properties
DEBUG:ApplicationFactory_impl - Assigned component AudioSink_1 to DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da
DEBUG:ApplicationFactory_impl - **PASSED** COMP INST_ID:AudioSink_1 IMPL:cpp
ERROR:ApplicationFactory_impl - Failed to instantiate component: 'AudioSink' with component id: 'AudioSink_1:Audio_test_waveform_142_114653655_1 assigned to device: 'DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da'  in waveform 'Audio_test_waveform_142_114653655_1';'configure' failed with Unknown Exception error occurred near line:3275 in file:ApplicationFactory_impl.cpp;
WARN:ApplicationFactory_impl - CF::ExecutableDevice::terminate failed for DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da; CORBA::Exception name: InvalidProcess
ERROR:ApplicationFactory_impl - Error in application creation; Failed to instantiate component: 'AudioSink' with component id: 'AudioSink_1:Audio_test_waveform_142_114653655_1 assigned to device: 'DCE:22e17539-e384-462f-8414-24024524a4da'  in waveform 'Audio_test_waveform_142_114653655_1';'configure' failed with Unknown Exception error occurred near line:3275 in file:ApplicationFactory_impl.cpp;
INFO:DomainManager_impl - Uninstalling application DCE:bfa10c69-0965-493a-b6ca-20e8895a6ae2`

Comment: Can you please post your device manager log? That will be more helpful than the domain manager log to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: The first one is my Device Manager log.
Can I understand anything from this log about my problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix has been submitted which probably addresses your problem. Please pull the latest version of the component and try again.