# How to make gnuhawk component AudioSink load to redhawk?

Tags: redhawksdr

Running `CentOS 6.5` and `RedHawk 1.9.0`, and I have audio-components installed in `$SDRROOT`, and AudioSink shows up in palette, all good.  However when I double click to launch it I get the error:

```
Launching component AudioSink_1 has encountered a problem
```

and

```
Failed to launch: AudioSink_1.
```

When I click on details I get:

```
Failed to launch: AudioSink_1
```

and

```
IDL:CF/ExecutableDevice/ExecuteFail:1.0
```

Not very informative. Components AudioSource and AudioTestSource also do not launch.

Comment: When you launch a component in the Sandbox (or any processes in the IDE), the component is launched as a separate process.  This is shown as a console in the IDE and used for logging & error statements.  Use the down arrow near the blue monitor button to view all your open consoles as shown here: http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/images/REDHAWK_Domain_Console.png

That console should provide you with additional information about the error and why the components will not launch.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a very similar issue to what you described when I was trying to use Axios-Engineering's RTLTcpSource component.  What the issue was for me was I was installing the component incorrectly. So for me this is how I installed a component in REDHAWK.

1. Download the original source code. (unzip if necessary)
2. Open the REDHAWK IDE(eclipse)
3. File->Import...->Existing Projects into Workspace->next->select the source code folder->Finish
4. Project->Build Project
5. Drag project folder to "Target SDR" in the SCA Explorer

I hope this helps you or anyone else.  I know there aren't really many places that tell you how to actually add an external component to REDHAWK and it took me a while to figure out to just treat it like a normal custom component.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using audiosink. The answer above by JD will work but make sure you re-gen the component since the code was made in 1.84 and there is a new codegen for 1.9.

It may also throw a message saying there are errors when exporting to the target SDR but that can mostly be ignored from my experience.

Similarly if you want more of an output, you can run the component/device through the terminal sandbox after building it and set "-Debug 4" to get more information.

Good luck!

edit: seems like a bug with audiosink was addressed: [AudioSink unknown error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23656772/audiosink-unknown-error)
you might want to just pull down the updated version and try that!